# Let $\gcd(x_1,n)=d_1, \gcd(x_2,n)=d_2$ where $1\le x_1,x_2\le n-1$. Find $\gcd(x_1,x_2)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

**Let $\gcd(x_1,n)=d_1, \gcd(x_2,n)=d_2$ where $1\le x_1,x_2\le n-1$, $n$  is a given positive fixed integer.
Find $\gcd(x_1,x_2)$.**

I am stuck at finding the $\gcd(x_1,x_2)$.
**My try**

Let $\gcd(x_1,x_2)=d$. Then $d\mid x_1,d\mid x_2$.
So $x_1=ad_1,x_2=bd_2$.

But I am stuck at how to use the facts $\gcd(x_1,n)=d_1, \gcd(x_2,n)=d_2$.
If someone could kindly help me out, I will be grateful.

Comment: Use the fact: $gcd(x_{1},n)=ax_{1}+bn$, for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $gcd(x_{2},n)=kx_{2}+ln$ for $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Andrew; how does that help

Comment: I guess $\gcd(x_1,x_2)=1$ too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem information is insufficient. Let $$n=2^{10}\times3^{10}\times5^{10}\times7^{10}$$
and $a=2\times 3\times p_1$ , $b=5\times 7\times p_2$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are two sufficiently small (and not necessarily distinct) primes greater than or equal to $11$. Hence $${d_1=6\\d_2=35\\\gcd(d_1,d_2)=1\\\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(p_1,p_2)}$$setting $p_1=p_2$ yields to any arbitrary value for $\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated solution (the old one was incorrect, you can find it in the edit history):

Let $d=\gcd(x_1,x_2)$. Write $x_1=a_1d_1$ and $x_2=a_2d_2$. Then $\gcd(d,d_1)$ divides $d$, so it divides $x_2$. $\gcd(d,d_1)$ also divides $d_1$, so it divides $n$. Therefore $\gcd(d,d_1)$ divides $\gcd(x_2,n)=d_2$, so it divides $\gcd(d_1,d_2)=1$.

Thus $d|a_1d_1$ and $\gcd(d,d_1)=1$. By [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), $d|a_1$. Similarly, $d|a_2$, so $d|\gcd(a_1,a_2)$. But $\gcd(a_1,a_2)|d$, so
$$\gcd(x_1,x_2)=\gcd(a_1,a_2)=\gcd(\frac{x_1}{d_1},\frac{x_2}{d_2})$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: hmm, I can think of three reasons: I poorly presented my answer, I gave the whole answer when the asker only wanted help (to be understood as a hint), or the answer itself is wrong. If it's the last case, I would be glad to see where my mistake is :)

Comment: Okay, so I realized the problem got updated, so I tried updating my solution... but I realized my reasoning was completely off! $d\nmid d_1$ does not imply $d|a_1$. I'll think about this some more...

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But unfortunately it does not solve my problem, the solution brings $\gcd(x_1,x_2)$ in terms of $a_1,a_2$ but $a_1,a_2$ are themeselves unknown variables

Comment: $a_1$ and $a_2$ are known, if you allow for euclidean division in the ring of integers, since they are respectively $x_1/d_1$ and $x_2/d_2$. I updated my answer to show that. If that doesn't satisfy you, then Mostafa Ayaz's answer shows that we cannot do any better.